# How do I get Alamofire to Encode this Url - it keeps dropping parameter

Tags: swift, macos, alamofire

I am trying to get Alamofire to encode this url as below using URLEncoded

> https://domain.com/rest/api/2/search?query=assignment=user123()%20order%20by%20lastUp%20desc

I have used the following code:

```
let endpoint = "https://domain.com/rest/api/2/search/"
 let params:[String:AnyObject] = ["query" : "","assignment" : "user123() order by lastUpdated desc"]
```

but when Alamofire encodes the url it drops the "query" parameter altogether and gives me this:

> https://domain.com/rest/api/2/search?assignment=user123()%20order%20by%20lastUp%20desc // query parameter missing

2. I have tried changing the parameters to this:

   let endpoint = "https://domain.com/rest/api/2/search/"
            let params:[String:AnyObject] = ["query" : "assignment=user123() order by lastUp desc"]

however it encodes the "=" sign as `%20%3D%20`

Does anyone have a suggestion, how I can get this to work?

Comment: What should the final `GET` URL look like?

Comment: It's listed at the top of the question in the first snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way to get it to work was just to not use parameters at all and put the full endpoint as is.

```
let endpointFull = https://domain.com/rest/api/2/search?query=assignment=user123()%20order%20by%20lastUp%20desc  

 Alamofire.request(.GET, endpointFull)
```

Would have been much nicer if we could specify the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I just rank a quick test with your URL, and here's my output URL:

`https://domain.com/rest/api/2/search/?assignment=user123%28%29%20order%20by%20lastUpdated%20desc&query=`

So as you can see, the `query` param has not been skipped, it's just placed at the end. The Alamofire class `ParameterEncoding.swift` sorts the keys alphabetically while constructing the URL.

Here's my code for reference:

```
    let endpoint = "https://domain.com/rest/api/2/search/"
    let params:[String:AnyObject] = ["query" : "","assignment" : "user123() order by lastUpdated desc"]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, endpoint, parameters: params)
        .responseData { response in


            if let str = response.request?.URLString {

                print("~~~URL~~~\n", str)

            } else {

                print("oops")
            }
    }
```

However, the main point here is that if your intention is to pass one key (`query`) and one value (`assignment=user123...`), then the `=` is right to be encoded to `%20%3D%20`.

Your server should decode this back to a `=` and use it as required.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it sorting and pass the parameters in the order they are added ? It's breaking the code

Comment: Well the only way now is to modify the source code. Change `for key in parameters.keys.sort(<){...}` to `for key in parameters.keys {...} ` in `ParameterEncoding.swift`.
For this you will have to add the classes manually to your project.
Alternately, you can fork the Alamofire repo, modify the `ParameterEncoding` class and add _your own_ git repo to your podfile.

Comment: Thanks @Vinod - It looks like just putting in the url as is was more simple, but thats a good approach. I might contribute a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting any URL encoder to not encode the = to %3D in a query string?

Try this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

When I enter this in the Encoder/Decoder above:

```
assignment=user123() order by lastUp desc
```

This is the output I get:

```
assignment%3Duser123()%20order%20by%20lastUp%20desc
```

Simply put, "=" is not URL safe and it will be encoded if provided in a parameter value in the query string

Comment: Are your sure ? I think might be up safe as iit's used to associate the parameter key with value  in a url eg domain.com/search?db=main