# Url issue in swift 3.0 using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to send sms and my url with numbers is "http://api.appname.my/sendSms.php?message=hello&phone=687985<6123488<60149041982" but it get shorten to this "http://api.appname.my/sendSms.php?message=hello&phone=687985" so why it is removing other numbers.Here is my code

```
  number = number + "60149041982"

    let url = "http://api.appname.my/sendSms.php?message=hello&phone=\(number)"

    Alamofire.request(url).response{ (responseObject) -> Void in
    print(responseObject)

    }
```

Comment: You may need to escape the "<": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url

Comment: Worth checking this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38732455/3927536

Comment: No actually it is required from api developer to add this to make seperation between numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your should encode the `<` character to `%3C`

```
let urlString = "http://api.appname.my/sendSms.php?message=hello&phone=\(number)"
let url = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
print("Result: " + url!)

// Result: http://api.appname.my/sendSms.php?message=hello&phone=687985%3C6123488%3C60149041982
```